# unable to login after creating admin account by code 1st migrations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization, asp.net-membership

Hi all I am new to mvc and was trying to build a page which is accessible only to admins so I added the following code to my configuration.cs (source for seeding membership -http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m1-intro&mode=live&clip=0&course=mvc4-building)

```
 internal sealed class Configuration :     DbMigrationsConfiguration<Riduk.Models.UsersContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(Riduk.Models.UsersContext context)
    {
        SeedMembership();
    }

    private void SeedMembership()
    {
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", true);
        var roles = (SimpleRoleProvider)Roles.Provider;
        var membership = (SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;
        if (!roles.RoleExists("admin"))
        {
            roles.CreateRole("admin");
        }

        if (!roles.RoleExists("vendor"))
        {
            roles.CreateRole("vendor");
        }
        if (!roles.RoleExists("guest"))
        {
            roles.CreateRole("guest");
        }


        if (membership.GetUser("xyz@pqr.com", false) == null)
        {
            WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("xyz@pqr.com", "password",
                new
                {
                    RegisteredDate = DateTime.Now,
                    Name = "Prabhat Yadav",
                    UserName = "prabhat",
                    Mobile = "",
                    Email = "",
                }, true);
        }
        if (!roles.GetRolesForUser("xyz@pqr.com").Contains("admin"))
        {
            roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] { "xyz@pqr.com" }, new[] { "admin" });
        }

    }
}
```

Account controller:-

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
            {
                using (UsersContext db = new UsersContext())
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Either of your email or password is wrong");
            return View(model);
        }
```

after updating-database user profile is created in the desired table, but when I trying to login by using that Id and password , Its coming directly at the error part, for other users that is not created by using migration and hence login part is working perfectly , but for admins created by migration its not working ....so please guide me to resolve the issue thank you.

additional info - I have two DBContext having base set to DefaultConnection I am not sure but this may be the cause of real problem-

1)dbContext for my database

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
    {
        public UsersContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }
    }
```

2)context that comes with default mvc web template

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

Comment: update your questions with the error you are getting

Comment: actually I am getting no errors, when I put break point at the 1st line of Login controller and checked the values then I see that modelState.Isvalid is true but the second thing websecurity.Login(........) doesn't works and become false somehow

Comment: just making sure, go to your webconfig file and check how many connection strings you have. it is possible that you have more than one configured for the same task

Comment: actually i have one connection string but I have two DBContext having base set to DefaultConnection-